# ssh keys and working of ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have been trying to understand the entire concept of ssh for a while. But still I haven't been able to get a hold on the concept. I have referenced various materials online -

[OpenSSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH?action=show&redirect=SSH%2FOpenSSH)

[what-is-the-difference-between-ssh_config-and-sshd_config/](https://prasadlinuxblog.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/what-is-the-difference-between-ssh_config-and-sshd_config/)

Following are my doubts -

1. Everytime we create a ssh key (and suppose we overwrite the id_rsa.pub file everytime), how does the remote server get notified about that? Does it get notified because it has already been added to the list of known hosts and there is some internal mechanism to tell those remote hosts that keys have changed. Or is it because of the file authorised keys?
2. If suppose I change my public key, can I change it back manually to any older keys that I generated. In that case will I be able to connect to the remote server I was connecting to before, using those old keys?
3. What exactly does doing an ssh in local host mean? What benefits does it provide since it makes a connection to the local machine which you can anyways access.

Any material which provides a detailed explanation of ssh is most welcome.
TIA :)

**NOTE** 
This is my first question in this community. Please let me know if this is not the right place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everytime we create a ssh key (and suppose we overwrite the id_rsa.pub file everytime), how does the remote server get notified about that?

There is no automatic notification.  Additionally, if you overwrite your existing keypair, and that was the only thing that permitted you access to the remote systems, you would no longer have access.  I strongly suggest you not overwrite keys.  Instead make multiple keys.  Then use your .ssh/config to define a key for a specific connection, or add all your active keys to an ssh agent.

Once you create a new keypair, you need to re-publish the public key to any hosts you need to be authenticated on.

When I generate my keys I tend to name them, and add a comment that includes they time they are generated.  So something like this.

```
ssh-keygen  -C zoredache_20160217_id -f zoredache_20160217_id_rsa
```

> If suppose I change my public key, can I change it back manually to any older keys that I generated.

Not if you overwrite/replace it.  Again, keep your old keypairs.  Keep your old keypairs.

> What benefits does it provide since it makes a connection to the local machine

There is very little reason to do this.  But, I have found a few, rare, applications that won't work properly, when I `sudo -i -u anotheraccount`.  When I `ssh anotheraccount@localhost` I can use those applications.  One example is disconnected GNU Screen sessions.  Screen is somewhat picky about ownership of the terminal used to re-connect.  Using SSH to another account makes it work.